# get variable from json response

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a GET function and response in JSON.
This is function:

```
$.ajax({
  contentType: 'application/json',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(msg){
    var result = JSON.stringify(msg);
    console.log(result);
  },
  error: error,
  type: 'GET',
  url: myurl
});
```

success response from `result` is like this:

```
{"response":{"values":[{"name":"john","sex":"male"}]}}
```

But when I try to get the `name` from response, I get an error!
This is the error:

```
for(var k in result){
  console.log(result[k]);
}
```

displays the letters

I tried this:

```
$.each(result,function(index, value){
    console.log(index, value);
});
```

but always get error.

Comment: Uhm, you just **stringified** it, it's a string now, not an object. Use `msg` directly instead.

Comment: Instead of telling a story about your code **post it**.

Comment: You're response is, itself, a JSON object. Meaning if you want to iterate the keys, you would just do `for (var k in msg)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the `JSON.stringify(msg.response)`. After which, `msg.response.values[0].name`
should give`john`

Comment: @KonstantinMokhov Updated the answer. Try now.

Comment: it's work! thk! and now, if i want to find name, where sex=male i'm need to loop this?

Comment: @KonstantinMokhov Yes, you need to loop through `msg.response.values` array. Please consider marking this answer as 'approved'

Answer (score 0):

The response that you are getting is itself a json object.You can iterate through the object and get the name from the object.

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Answer (score 0):

You can access the value from json itself

```js
var response = {"response":{"values":[{"name":"john","sex":"male"}]}};

var getName = response.response.values[0].name;

alert(getName);
```